# Angular2: return http..get status after failure

Tags: angular

I am trying to return the status of a http.get request after failure, but the below code does not work:

```
fileExists(url){
        var status="";
        this.http.get(url)
                  .map(res => res.json())
                  .subscribe(
                      data => console.log(data),
                      err =>{
                              console.log(err.status)
                               status=err.status});
        console.log("Status is: "+status);
        return status;
  }
```

I expected  `status=err.status` set the status in the variable, but it doesn't work

Comment: `console.log("Status is: "+status);` would print `status` as `""` because it get evaluate before `http.get` call accomplish

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with `res` to be able to do `res.status` then.

As soon as you get the `res.json()` you lose the status, as well as other info. What `res.json()` does is to return you an object version of what's inside `res._body`

See [Angular2 responses](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html).

Comment: what u say makes sense, but can u right a bit of the code

Comment: I don't know how can i get the res.json in the fialure part

Comment: @KamyarParastesh You will have to run `res.json()` on your own inside the subscribe success. It will be then when it will fail if the json is invalid, which doesn't necessary mean `!== 200`.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will store the `http request` status inside a variable. The variable with `status` is revealed on the screen after sending request.

```
export class App {

  private status: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get(`someNotExistingJSON.json`)
        .subscribe(res => {
                console.log("success")
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err.status);
                this.status = err.status;
            }
        )
  };

  getStatus(){
    console.log(this.status);
  }
}
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wQQQAGixmYnEHcRBbYfY?p=preview)**